# How to make multiple forms to run after each action? The predecesor form is closed and new form is reached out to perform different actions?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, form-control, .net-4.8

I have form 1 as the initial form in `Application.Run()`. What should I do to run multiple forms, each closing after the `double_click()` action?

This Function is used in Main() method please refer. When the frm1 closes the execution also closes.

```
Application.Run(new frm1());
```

then

```
// frm1 closes
Application.Run(new frm2());
```

after that

```
//form 2 also closes
Application.Run(new frm3());
```

How to make this functionality work?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by… _”to run miltiple forms each closing after the double_click() action.”_ … ? … And what does the posted code do or not do in relation to your question?

Comment: If you have time to look at the documentation for Application.Run you will find even an example where two forms are started. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.run?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#system-windows-forms-application-run(system-windows-forms-applicationcontext). Still wondering why people take all the time to write a question when the first thing they should do is look at the docs of the method the will want to use.